# Issue a citation based on speed, with lenience for your birthday

Tags: java

You are driving a little too fast, and a police officer stops you. Write 
 code to compute the result, encoded as an int value: 0=no ticket, 1=small 
 ticket, 2=big ticket. If speed is 60 or less, the result is 0. If speed is 
 between 61 and 80 inclusive, the result is 1. If speed is 81 or more, the 
 result is 2. Unless it is your birthday -- on that day, your speed can be 
 5 higher in all cases.

```
public int caughtSpeeding(int speed, boolean isBirthday) {
if(isBirthday) {
    if(speed <= 65) {
        return 0;
    } else if(66 <= speed && speed <= 85) {
        return 1;
    } else if(86 <=  speed) {
        return 2;
    }
}

if(speed <= 60) {
    return 0;
} else if(61 <= speed && speed <= 80) {
    return 1;
} else {
    return 2;
}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function should probably be `static`, since it does not rely on any instance variables.

On your birthday, *your speed can be 5 higher in all cases* — so don't make three more cases for the birthday.

If you have already determined that the speed is not `<= 60`, then there is no point in testing `61 <= speed` — that will always be the case.

Since all three branches similarly return an expression, I would use a ternary statement.

```
public static int caughtSpeeding(int speed, boolean isBirthday) {
    int birthdayAdjustedSpeed = isBirthday ? speed - 5 : speed;
    return (birthdayAdjustedSpeed <= 60) ? 0 :
           (birthdayAdjustedSpeed <= 80) ? 1 :
                                           2;
}
```

Comment: why it is speed - 5? the question is said that your speed can be 5 higher in all cases

Comment: Reducing the speed by 5 is effectively the same as increasing the 3 speed limits by 5 with only one operation.